# Import error no function named 'get_achieve' while importing from Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to run a script. In the script this line is causing error:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.cliutils.archive_viewer import get_archive, get_data, get_content, get_archive_content
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.utils.cliutils.archive_viewer import get_archive, get_data, get_content, get_archive_content
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_archive' from 'PyInstaller.utils.cliutils.archive_viewer'
```

I'm thinking maybe its because the PyInstaller has been updated, and the '`get_archive`' function is no longer exist. Anyone know which version of `PyInstaller` have this function and where can I download it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: See the comments/solutions [here](https://github.com/serfend/pydumpck/issues/27).